# Django voting system: Prevent duplicate votes

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a forum used Django. I have many things working, including voting. The one thing I can't figure out is preventing duplicate voting. How could I get this to work? Is there a way you could possibly use JS to make a form in HTML only able to send once? Or would I have to perform some special operation in the view? Here is my code in the template:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="ui container segment">
    <img class="ui avatar image" src="/{{ comment.by.userprofile.img.url }}"><b>{{ comment.by }}</b>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">{{ comment.body }}</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Thumbs up" class="ui small blue button">
        <i class="thumbs up outline icon"></i>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ comment.id }}" name="comment">
    </form>
    <span>{{ comment.points }}</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And my code in the views:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    print request.POST
    if 'body' in request.POST.keys():
        reply = ForumReply.objects.create(by=request.user, reply_to=post, body=request.POST['body'])
        reply.save()
        notification = Notification.objects.create(to=post.by, message='Your post "' + post.title + '" received a new reply')
        notification.save()
    if 'comment' in request.POST.keys():
        comment = post.forumreply_set.filter(pk=request.POST['comment'])[0]
        comment.points += 1
        comment.save()
```

And my model (Per request of Lego Stormtroopr)

```
class ForumReply(models.Model):
    by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey(ForumPost)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Show us the model you are using to store votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found a solution to my problem, but I'm certain it's not the most elegant. However, it works as I need it to.

So, what I've done is create a ManyToManyField on the UserProfile. All Users have a OneToOne relationship with a UserProfile.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.TextField(default='This user hasn\'t said anything about themselves yet')
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=gen_name, default="static/imgs/default/default_user.jpg")
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    liked_replies = models.ManyToManyField(ForumReply)
```

Whenever a user likes a reply, it is saved to that ManyToManyField. Then in the view, it checks to see if that comment is in the current user's list of liked replies, and if it is, it doesn't add the vote.

```
if 'comment' in request.POST.keys():
    comment = post.forumreply_set.filter(pk=request.POST['comment'])[0]
    if not comment in request.user.userprofile.liked_replies.all():
        print 'liked'
        comment.points += 1
        comment.save()
        request.user.userprofile.liked_replies.add(comment)
        request.user.userprofile.save()
```

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it. Why do you think its inellegant?

Comment: Not sure. I don't have very much experience when it comes to web development, so if I ever find a solution to a problem, I never necessarily think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to prevent double voting on the server, not in javascript. Otherwise someone could write a malicious script to mess up your voting system database. There are a few solutions, lets start wit the easiest:

1) On the server, you'll need to check if the user has voted before. Adding something like the following:

`voted_before = len(ForumReply.objects.filter(by=request.user, reply_to=post)[:1]) > 1`

Then you can check if `voted_before` is `True` before adding the new vote.

2) However, that **the first solution is subject to race conditions**. If one user **simultaneously** casts the same vote twice, it's possible that the server will not detect that it voted before.

To avoid the race conditions, you're only using one server, and there is only one django process running, you can use `threading.Lock` to prevent the check from occurring multiple times.

3) If you're using multiple servers and a distributed database, you'll need to use something called transactions. These are usually database specific.